# How to write the signature of isinstance (with type narrowing)

Tags: python, python-3.x, mypy, python-typing

for some performance reasons I have reimplemented the isinstance builtin function with slight modifications that works faster under my constraints. Now I'm trying to make mypy happy with my function by adding a propper signature. **What should be the signature of the isinstance function?**

I found a way to do the simple case, where the second argument is a type.

```py
T = TypeVar("T")

def constrained_isinstance(obj: Any, cls: Type[T]) -> TypeGuard[T]:
    pass  # let's not bother about implementation
```

However, I can't find a way to write a signature for tuple of types case (ex: `isinstance(pet, (Dog, Cat))`). I thought about using [`TypeVarTuple`](https://peps.python.org/pep-0646/); the closest I got from a solution is this signature:

```py
T = TypeVarTuple("T")

def constrained_isinstance(obj: Any, types: tuple[*T]) -> TypeGuard[Union[*T]]:
    pass
```

This is a wrong solution because narrowed types would be `Union[Type[Cat], Type[Dog]]` instead of `Union[Cat, Dog]`

There might be a way to explicit types of several elements like `Types[*T]` but I couldn't find it.

PS: A workaround would be to write this in the stub file:

```py
constrained_isinstance = isinstance
```

But I would love to find a more beautiful way.

Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found a better solution by using [`class.__instancecheck__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#class.__instancecheck__), which allow me to use my modified version while calling builtin `isinstance`.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).